# Woocommerce customized template not working for logged in user

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I have an issue with custom template with Woocommerce.

When i check my page (archive-product.php) when i'm a visitor, I see my custom template.

But if I see with a administrator, the Archive-product.php in the woocommerce plugin template is displayed.

I don't use woocommerce.php in my theme.

** 
I have copy `plugins/woocommerce/templates/*` to `myTheme/woocommerce/*`

Any idea with this strange issue?

thank you!

Comment: I had same issue, i just disabled woocommerce template debug mode and everything back to good, i do not why but i works, it can be little bug

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you need a woocommerce.php in your template folder. The woocommerce.php serves to display WC taxonomies pages etc.

> This problem can potentially affect the shop page, the single product
>   page and the taxonomy pages (categories and tags) because WooCommerce
>   uses templates of its own to display these pages, and it’s impossible
>   for WooCommerce to know exactly what markup your theme uses.

For a better understanding take a look at the official docs page: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/

It's because WC needs the "woocommerce_content()" to display special WC pages.

You should also declare that your theme supports WC. Use this simple Snippet in your functions.php (also described in the link above):

```php
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'woocommerce_support' );
function woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
```

Comment: The theme is already used by woocommerce. the supports WC is already in function. And Woocommerce.php is not needed in the themes. 
Well, Like "Mohamad Ali" said in comment, uncheck debug mode works.